# Angular Material get latest version | md-chips : read only, removable

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

For my applications I need to use the `<chips>` directive from **Angular-Material**.

The chips need to be *read only* (no input) but *still removable*. This feature is **not** implemented in the latest released version : see https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc.5/demo/chips

But it **is** implemented on the MASTER version : see https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/chips

The feature I look for : 
[image] Is there any *easy* or *right* way to get this version in my app ?

I know this question might be simple and I apologize for that, I just never had this problem before so I wanted to make sure I am doing the right thing !

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [installation documents](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/#installing-angular-material):

> bower install 'angular-material#master'

I did this and then did a search for the string "removable" in **angular-material.js** and it is found in the code for `MdChipsCtrl`.

Comment: It worked ! I just wanted to add (for people using PlayFramework) that you will need to move your bower_components directory inside of the public or any other Assets directory you defined in your routes.